# Checking baggage at Heathrow on BA

Tags: luggage, lhr

I have a connecting flight from Heathrow but I arrive on a non-affiliated flight 10 hours earlier. I know I can check-in for my BA flight well before it actually departs but when I can drop off my baggage? Ideally, I'd like to drop-off my baggage for the BA flight then just go relax in the lounge before my flight. The other option is to sit and wait in Terminal 5 for 6 hours with my suitcase....I don't like that choice much!
I checked the BA site and they have lots of info on what I can take and how much and the size, etc but I found nothing on when I can actually drop-off my bag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the information for Heathrow Terminal 5 [here](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/airport-information/london-heathrow-airport/heathrow-t5).

It's either three hours before the flight, or anytime after 5AM depending on which class you are flying.

Comment: AH...I see. Thanks. Since I don't fit into any of those classes, I am out of luck.